# Shinyjs toggle doesn't work if included in a package

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I used `shinyjs::toggle` in an R script, where I have the `ui` and `server` functions in the same file. This way it worked wonderful, however once I use the exact same code in 2 separate files (a `ui.R` and a `server.R`) as part of a package, it does not work any more. There are no error messages, the function simply does not show and hide the element I use it for.

I tried it with the minimal example below, with the same result.
As a standalone R-script it works, once I use the same functions in a package it does not.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
 dashboardHeader(),
 dashboardSidebar(),
 dashboardBody(
   useShinyjs(),
   actionButton("button", "Click me"),
   div(id = "hello", "Hello!")
 )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 observeEvent(input$button, {
   toggle("hello")
 })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In a package:

```
#' Shiny App UI
#'
#' @import shiny
#' @import shinydashboard
#' @import  shinyjs
#'
#'


uitest <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    actionButton("button", "Click me"),
    div(id = "hello", "Hello!")
  )
)


#' Shiny app server function
#'
#' @param input provided by shiny
#' @param output provided by shiny
#'



servertest <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    toggle("hello")
  })
}
```

Can anyone please help me out here? What might go wrong?

Comment: Try placing the files into a directory where there are no other R-files and try again

Comment: Thanks, I've tried. Now I have only 3 R-files in my directory, `ui.R`, `server.R` and a `launchapp.R` actually starting the shiny-app. Unfortunately still the same result, it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

When the package is loaded the UI is already pre-build and the function `useShinyjs()` that was included in the `ui.R` script is no longer triggered. In my package, I have created a launchApp function that can launch my app and it calls `useShinyjs()` prior to launching the app. So I have 3 separate R files: `ui.R`, `server.R` and `launchApp.R`.

```
launchApp <- function() {

  shinyjs::useShinyjs()

  shinyApp(ui, server)

}
```

Comment: Yes, yes, yes!!! I have been trying several hours to put `useShinyjs()` in the correct place, but didn't think of this!! Thank you so much!!!!